# TypeError: Object of type 'User' is not JSON serializable

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

How to return a list of objects in Django Rest Framework.I am calling a function which returns list of objects.

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
import json

class MyView(APIView):
    from .serializers import MySerializer
    from app.permissions import MyPermissionClass
    from .models import MyModel

    serializer_class = MySerializer
    queryset = MyModel.objects.all()
    permission_classes = (MyPermissionClass,)
    pagination_class = None

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data=myfunction(a,b,c)
        # data={list}<class 'list'>: [<User: Negiiii | negiiii>, <User: Negiiii | negiiii>]
        data=json.dumps(data)
        return Response({"data":data})
```

Result that I need:

```
[
  {
    "name":"Negi",
    "rollno":14
   },
  {
    "name":"Negi",
    "rollno":13
  }
]
```

Comment: Is that a **`User`** model Queryset?

Comment: can you add the `MySerializer` class?

Answer (score 1):

You can use DRF Serializers to serialize the data.
First you need to define a serializer class as,

```
# serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers


class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = UserModel
        fields = ('name', 'rollno')
```

and then, use the **`UserSerializer`** in your views as,

```
def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    data = myfunction(a, b, c)
    response_data = UserSerializer(data, many=True)
    return Response({"data": response_data.data})
```

Comment: Instead of using response_data = MySerializer(data, many=True) I have used response=self.get_serializer(data, many=True) Thank you for your help!

Comment: I could've written a better answer if you'd provide right info at the right time :)